# Can't find a solution to a somewhat complex and unusual requirements

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, database-design

I am working on a CMS using ASP.NET / C#. It works fine and life is good. However, it was decided to add extra functionality to support a wider variety of websites.
Basically, the current CMS is still alpha but will be able to host data for multiple websites running for the same group of companies all having somewhat the same requirements.

I have constructed the database as per the diagram attached below:

"Image removed for security reasons"

Now, in addition to this diagram, I was asked to add support for products under different 'attributes' than Sectors. Meaning that a product now can have a `type` and many other attributes. So let's say you're using one of our sites and we make tissue paper. Products should somehow support filtering by 'type' say 'tissue' and by 'application' say 'how you use it' and other unknown 'attributes' that may pop up in the future.

For example a product may fall under the 'Agricultural Packaging' sector and is of type 'Bag' and is applied by some way of applying it.
The end result is to be able to sort products by how they are used and or their type and or the sector they fall under. Or even all together.

What is the best approach for this sort of problem to include into the data model and the CMS?

Thanks!

Comment: read Enterprise Model Patterns by Hay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're taking the right approach.  If a product can be assigned more than one of the new 'attributes', then you'll want to create a new Attributes table where you can define a finite set of attributes.  Then link that table to Products via a cross-reference table, just like you're doing with Products & Sectors.  If a Product can only be assigned a singe attribute, then add the Attributes table, but instead of using a cross-reference table, add an AttributeID column to the Products table to join the two.

I feel like I may be telling you something that you already know, however.  So if there is any additional information, or more specifics you want, maybe you can post an update.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are looking for is called [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)
You will end up with an attribute table and an attribute value table that has the product id, attribute id, and attribute value in in it.